# facing issue to store value in state and 3rd time state is not updating in react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I am trying to get value from the radio button the problem is I can get the values but when I tried to store on my state it only updates 2 times after the 3rd time when I try to update the state it is not updating.

Radio buttons code.

```
              <li>
                <label className="container_radio">
                  Small
                  <span>+ $5</span>
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    required
                    onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, product)}
                    defaultValue={5}
                    name={"size"}
                  />
                  <span className="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <label className="container_radio">
                  Medium
                  <span>+ $10</span>
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    required
                    onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, product)}
                    defaultValue={10}
                    name={"size"}
                  />
                  <span className="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <label className="container_radio">
                  Large
                  <span>+ $15</span>
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    required
                    onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, product)}
                    defaultValue={15}
                    name={"size"}
                  />
                  <span className="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
              </li>
```

I am trying to achieve output something like this

```
[{title: 'Barnes Chapman', options:{Medium size: '5.00' } }]
```

My ui:

[image]

My function: problem is here `if (isExist) { isExist.options = { ...isExist.options, [name]: value, }; return prevValue;` for this code the state is not updaing unlimited time.

```
  const handleChange = (e, product) => {
    // Destructuring
    const { name, value, checked } = e.target;

    console.log(`${value} is ${checked} `);

    // Case 1 : The user checks the box
    if (checked) {
      setProductInfo((prevValue) => {
        const isExist = prevValue.find((item) => item.title === product.title);
        if (isExist) {
          isExist.options = {
            ...isExist.options,
            [name]: value,
          };
          return prevValue;
        } else {
          return [
            ...prevValue,
            {
              title: product.title,
              options: { [name]: value },
            },
          ];
        }
      });
    }

    // Case 2  : The user unchecks the box
    else {
      setProductInfo(productinfo.filter((e) => e.title !== name));
    }
  };
```

Comment: please share more code. Especially which kind of array does `productinfo` hold?

Comment: it's just a state which will store the radio button value and product title `  const [productinfo, setProductInfo] = useState([]);
`

Comment: could you show me sample for an item in the array?

Comment: Why are you returning the previous state if the ```isExist``` is true?

Comment: @Liki above function output `[options: {size: '15'}
title: "Carroll Montgomery"]`  if you want to play with my code here is the link of codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/embed/friendly-bird-ldqvb0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: @OsamuRenji I am retruning `previous state ` beacsue after 3rd time when I try to update the state it give me an error which is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')
`

Comment: @Jerin It means the item was not found. ```find``` method return ```undefined``` if the value was not found in the array.

Comment: @OsamuRenji I consoled `isExisit` but I didn't get any undefined, every time it gives me an object even after 3rd time when I try to update the state

Comment: So the component isn't re-rendering even though you return ```prevValue```. Is that your problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243853/discussion-between-jerin-and-osamu-renji).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few problems in your code.

**1. Don't change state variable directly.**

In the following code, you are trying to change `state` variable directly. This may result unexpected result.

```
const isExist = prevValue.find((item) => item.title === product.title);
if (isExist) {
  isExist.options = {
    ...isExist.options,
    [name]: value,
  };
  return prevValue;
}
```

You can read more about it.

[Why can't I directly modify a component's state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755997/why-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really)

**2. In this code, you should compare array item by `title` instead of `name`.
Because you are using `title`.**

```
    // Case 2  : The user unchecks the box
    else {
      setProductInfo(productinfo.filter((e) => e.title !== name));
    }
```

**3. Updated code based on your code in codesandbox**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [productinfo, setProductInfo] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (e, product) => {
    // Destructuring
    const { name, value, checked } = e.target;

    console.log(`${value} is ${checked} ${product.title}`);

    // Case 1 : The user checks the box
    if (checked) {
      setProductInfo((prevValue) => {
        const newValue = prevValue ? [...prevValue] : [];
        const isExist = newValue.find((item) => item.title === product.title);
        if (isExist) {
          isExist.options = {
            ...isExist.options,
            [name]: value,
          };
          return newValue;
        } else {
          return [
            ...newValue,
            {
              title: product.title,
              options: { [name]: value },
            },
          ];
        }
      });
    }

    // Case 2  : The user unchecks the box
    else {
      setProductInfo(productinfo.filter((e) => e.title !== product.title));
    }
  };
  console.log(productinfo, "state");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul className="clearfix">
        {/* {product.options.map((option, i) => {
                return ( */}
        <li>
          <label className="container_radio">
            Small
                  <span>+ $5</span>
            <input
              type="radio"
              required
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, { title: "title" })}
              defaultValue={5}
              name={"size"}
            />
            <span className="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
          <label className="container_radio">
            Medium
                  <span>+ $10</span>
            <input
              type="radio"
              required
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, { title: "title" })}
              defaultValue={10}
              name={"size"}
            />
            <span className="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
          <label className="container_radio">
            Large
                  <span>+ $15</span>
            <input
              type="radio"
              required
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, { title: "title" })}
              defaultValue={15}
              name={"size"}
            />
            <span className="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
        </li>
        {/* ); */}
        {/* // })} */}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```